# QuerySyntaxException when trying to get the number of rows in the table

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

On running the following snippet

```
String hqlCount = "select count(*) from person";
int count = (Integer)sess.createQuery(hqlCount).uniqueResult();
```

I get this exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: person is not mapped [select count(*) from person]

org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:158)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:255)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
servlets.InsertPerson.doPost(InsertPerson.java:43)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I have already mapped the `person` class to `person` table by creating hibernate mapping file named `person.hbm.xml` and added this tag to hibernate configuration file `<mapping resource="person.hbm.xml"/>`

Comment: Please check if the class name is same as you mention in your mapping file. **Case matters**

Answer (score 0):

The exception states that - the table `person` is not mapped to any entity class.

Please create mapping for the table (using `@Entity`)

```
@Entity
@Table(name='person')
class Person {


}
```

Comment: I already made a mapping xml named `person.hbm.xml` which maps person class to person table

Comment: Have you added this mapping xml in hibernate configuration xml ?

Comment: I have added a tag in cfg file `<mapping resource="person.hbm.xml"/>`

Comment: @Y.E.P - Not withstanding that you *say* that you have mapped the class, this is what the exception message *says* is the problem.  You need to look at *how* you mapped the class ... and why Hibernate is saying that you haven't.  Did you make a mistake?